# Django aggregate query with filters

Tags: django, django-models

i have two tables.Template and Tracker tables. with one to many relationship.
i need to show all the uploaded templates for a particular user. also i need to order by with the download count.

i tried the following query. but it's not getting the all downloaded count.

```
Template.objects.filter(tracker__type='upload', user_id=300).annotate(
    download_count=Count(
       'tracker',
       filter=Q(tracker__type='download')
    )
).order_by("-download_count")
```

Template Table

| id | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | AAA |
| 2 | AAA | AAA |
| 3 | AAA | AAA |

Tracker Table

| id | type | user_id | template_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | download | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | download | 200 | 1 |
| 3 | upload | 300 | 1 |

Comment: Why do you filter on `tracker_type='upload'`? Based on your template table, there is no `tracker_type` in the `Template` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem double underscore missed. tracker is the related name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) and then annotate the `Template`s:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Exists, OuterRef

Template.objects.filter(
    Exists(Tracker.objects.filter(
        template_id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id=300, tracker_type='upload'
    ))
).annotate(
    total_downloads=Count('tracker', filter=Q(tracker__type='download'))
).order_by('-total_downloads')
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of `Template`s that have been uploaded by a user with as primary key `300` and these `Template` objects will contain an extra attribute `.total_downloads` that will list the number of downloads for that `Template`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, if this user has multiple uploaded templates is this query works ?

Comment: @WAEX: then the queryset will return multiple templates: each template that was uploaded by that user.

Comment: i tried out but ordering is not working.

Comment: @WAEX: did you use `.order_by('-total_downloads')` at the end? Exaclty what are the values for `.total_downloads`?